# How to wait till real time output starts coming on console in a subprocess?

Tags: python, windows, console, subprocess

**UseCase:**

Invoke a command in Windows CMD shell. Wait till output (logs) start coming on the console. Output (log) on the console must not run in background.

```
import subprocess 
from subprocess import CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
command="cmd /K appium -p 4723"
#This open a new cmd shell for above command
proc=Popen(command,creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
#Need to write further code , based on wait till the logging started
```

**Expected :**
Want to wait till the logging started on console

**Logs on Console.**

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.7.0
[HTTP] Could not start REST http interface listener. The requested port may already be in use. Please make sure there is no other instance of this server running already.
```

Comment: I changed "terminal" to "shell" in your question. CMD is a text user interface shell for administering a system. It uses standard input, output, and error streams. A terminal is a screen with keyboard/mouse input, which possibly handles virtual terminal escape codes for formatting. A terminal can provide standard I/O. A program could be both a console/terminal and a shell, but CMD is not. The latest version of the Windows console is implemented in condrv.sys (kernel driver) and conhostv2.dll, and hosted in conhost.exe -- which are implementation details. What matters is the console API.

Comment: I looked into this in generic terms of [console WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-winevents). But it's a race condition between creating the console window, setting the hook to filter console WinEvents for just that window, and the child process writing to the console. It's easy to miss the events for the write. So I don't think  a generic solution is advisable.

Comment: You can spawn python.exe attached to the new console and have this child instance of Python spawn "cmd" or "appium". The child Python can then wait for text to be written to *its console* and then signal the parent Python in some way (write to a pipe, set an event, etc).